# Error when creating a contour plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a matrix and I want to make a contour plot. At first, I tried the `contour` function in R, which gives me the plot shown below.

However, the contour lines are not smooth and the x & y labels are not correct. So I want to use `ggplot2` to make a smooth contour plot. However, `ggplot2` produces an error:

```
Computation failed in `stat_contour()`:
  Contour requires single `z` at each combination of `x` and `y`.
```

---

The data is available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/1obn2xxcra10usl/data1.rdata?dl=0

```
load("data1.rdata",.GlobalEnv)
contour(data1)
```

[image]

This is the code I tried to use in `ggplot2`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
data1_melt = melt(data1)
names(data1_melt) <- c("y", "x", "pr")

ggplot(data1_melt, aes(x = x, y = y, z = pr)) + stat_contour()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from duplicated `y` values. If you look at the original `data1` you will see repeated row names, probably due to rounding or decimals truncation. You must first keep only unique values.

Remove the duplicated `y` values.

```
sp <- split(data1_melt, data1_melt$x)
sp <- lapply(sp, function(DF) {
  i <- !duplicated(DF[["y"]])
  DF[i, ]
})

data1_melt <- do.call(rbind, sp)
rm(sp)

ggplot(data1_melt, aes(x = x, y = y, z = pr)) +
  geom_contour()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, my data actually include repeated values, how can we deal with this? Also, the contour plot you make is still not smooth, could you fix that? Thanks a lot.